# jar file not reading correct properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have managed to create a jar file with the libraries packaged in a separate folder. I want to be able to deploy the jar, folder and separate properties file on different servers and it seemed to run fine. But each jar file seems to be reading the same properties file no matter what changes I make to each property file. What is the correct way to create this jar with an external properties file?

My project is setup with the properties file under /src/main/resources and the main class under /src/main/java and I call the file as follows:

```
fileProp.load(configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the properties file from inside the jar file. Would it not be better to read the file in as a normal file

```
File file = new File('config/config.properties');
fileProp.load(file);
......
```

Comment: Yes but I need to change the file contents each time i deploy an instance of the jar file. Would this still work?

Comment: yes the only difference is that you would need to deploy the jar and the config file in tandem. You would have 2 files to deploy for each jar and config combination.

Comment: NP. Maybe just mark this as the correct answer so others don't have to sift through multiple answers to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your properties file in **same package as your class** to read it like this

```
configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
```

Or you can place properties file relative to your current directory and read it by

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("config.properties") so if I understand correctly, this will allow me to add the properties file to anywhere I deploy the jar

Comment: I went with Jacques answer just as he was able to confirm my additional queries. Thanks a lot though for responding. I will try this as well to check if it works in my case.

Comment: Yup it will allow you to do that. Just keep your properties file relative to your jar location.